# Why adb push gives device not found error?

Tags: android, shell, adb

I want to push some `apk` file to `sd` card, then to `/system` folder. I tried the following commands in order:

```
adb shell

su

mount -o rw,remount /system

adb push /data/app/com.project.android.xxx-2.apk /sdcard
```

But the last line always results in **device not found** error. I have even tried with system folder directly as, `adb push /data/app/com.project.android.xxx-2.apk /system/app`, but it gave me the same error. I have also tried to execute this line before push command:

```
chmod 644 /sdcard
```

But that didn't solve the push command problem.

- My device is rooted.
- Device driver is updated.
- My device has sd card.
- USB debugging mode is enabled.
- When I write `adb devices` I get my device name.

What is causing this error, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing `adb push` being already `shell`-ed into the device. By doing that you start another `adb` server on the target device now (not on your host machine), which is scanning ports in [some range](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) looking for devices attached. Since no device is found (attached to the target device) you get `error: device not found`. For the kind of task you're trying to achieve no need to use any of `adb` commands **within** `shell`.

Try either `mv` or `cp` command once you `shell`-ed in. For example (remounting part skipped):

```
adb shell
cp /data/app/com.project.android.xxx-2.apk /sdcard
```